# Unable to figure this join giving wrong results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables I want to join but I am unable to get the desired answer.
I am trying to joing two table on the base of two primary key and grouping thrid column and want to get count of third column.

Table 1:

```
╔══════╦══════╗
║ D_ID ║ E_ID ║
╠══════╬══════╣
║    5 ║   25 ║
║    5 ║   26 ║
║    5 ║   27 ║
║   10 ║   30 ║
║   10 ║   31 ║
║   10 ║   32 ║
╚══════╩══════╝
```

Table 2:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ D_ID ║ E_ID ║ L_ID ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║    5 ║   25 ║    1 ║
║    5 ║   25 ║    2 ║
║    5 ║   25 ║    3 ║
║    5 ║   25 ║    4 ║
║    5 ║   26 ║    5 ║
║    5 ║   26 ║    6 ║
║    5 ║   26 ║    7 ║
║    5 ║   26 ║    8 ║
║    5 ║   27 ║    9 ║
║   10 ║   30 ║   10 ║
║   10 ║   30 ║   11 ║
║   10 ║   31 ║   12 ║
║   10 ║   31 ║   13 ║
║   10 ║   32 ║   14 ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Desired Output:

```
╔══════╦══════╦═════════════╗
║ D_ID ║ E_ID ║ Count(L_ID) ║
╠══════╬══════╬═════════════╣
║    5 ║   25 ║           4 ║
║    5 ║   26 ║           4 ║
║    5 ║   27 ║           1 ║
║   10 ║   30 ║           2 ║
║   10 ║   31 ║           2 ║
║   10 ║   32 ║           1 ║
╚══════╩══════╩═════════════╝
```

Using this Query:

```
select a.D_ID, a.E_ID, count(b.L_ID)
from table1 a, table2 b
where a.D_ID = b.D_ID and
      a.E_ID = b.E_ID 
group by a.D_ID, a.E_ID
```

Join is important because table 2 is **huge** table with millions of records and table 1 has only few thousand records that what I need. I dont need all `D_ID` and `E_ID`'s. I only need those `D_ID` and `E_ID` which are in `Table1`.

Comment: why do you need a join?

Comment: Your query should work on the data provided in the question.

Comment: Just use SQL FIDDLE to help: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9a6b2/1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

just add a DISTINCT clause to the count like so

```
SELECT 
    a.D_ID, a.E_ID, COUNT(DISTINCT b.L_ID)
FROM table1 a, table2 b
WHERE a.D_ID = b.D_ID 
  AND a.E_ID = b.E_ID 
GROUP BY a.D_ID, a.E_ID
```

my personal preference for joining tables is like so

```
SELECT a.d_id, a.e_id, COUNT(DISTINCT b.l_id)
FROM table1 a
JOIN table2 b ON a.D_ID = b.D_ID 
             AND a.E_ID = b.E_ID 
GROUP BY a.D_ID, a.E_ID
```

see this [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f9f6/4) executing all two queries with the correct result set

Comment: why arent you including D_ID in the GROUP BY?

Comment: @barryhunter because it doesn't need it.. look at the result set.. the group by d_id is only needed when joining the other table.. because theres duplicates caused -- however it could be easily added

Comment: True, for that example set, but didnt seem to be any evidence, that it would always be the case. I wondered if you saw some :)

Comment: @barryhunter that is true that this is making that assumption.. from the result set the op posted theres multiple e_id's for each d_id so it would seem like that will always be the case, or at least one e_id for a d_id.. since performance is a big deal I figured it a waste to group by both if you are only pulling from that one table.. in any case the OP can see these comments and adjust accordingly if my underlying assumption is incorrect :)

Comment: You are considering this example only. The Table1 could be a table to filter values from Table2. If it is the case, then join is necessary

Comment: @Nizam which is why i also posted a way to do it with a join?

Comment: @Nizam if you really think its an issue see the demo i posted. -- also when someone posts the structure of a table.. its generally a good bet that thats how the data is laid out

Comment: I just said the first answer was not considering all the aspects of the question. The edition made the answer much better and I think it is good now.

Comment: Table 2 is Huge table with million of records. but i need to get only few as Table 1 that's why both tables are necessary.

Comment: @user3802500 ok you should use the last query i posted then.. that last query is the correct and accepted way to join a table rather than doing the Cartesian Product of the two tables. if you have any questions about it feel free to ask.. also see the demo I posted

Comment: @user3802500 if you wouldn't mind I would appreciate you marking this answer as accepted when you can. thanks